# Bind F1 to smart contextual documentation (help buffers)

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp, ess

Is there a command which I could bind to <kbd>F1</kbd> in Emacs that would give me (in
a temporary or persistent buffer) contextual documentation on the "symbol" under
point?

IIUC, that'd give the same results as:

- <kbd>C-c C-v</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> in ESS buffers (= `ess-display-help-on-object`)
- <kbd>C-h f</kbd>/<kbd>C-h v</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd> in Emacs Lisp buffers (= `describe-function`/`describe-variable`)
- <kbd>C-h S</kbd> in Shell buffers (= `info-lookup-symbol`) + <kbd>M-x</kbd> `man-follow`
- ??? in AWK, C, Java
- ??? in AUCTeX buffers (well, that may be a big dream ;-))
- ...

Somehow, Auto-Complete does that job (at least in ESS and Emacs Lisp buffers),
as it displays the right help (on functions, on variables, etc.) in its "quick
help" tooltip. Though, it's only displayed during the completion process, not after.

I first thought that `info-lookup-symbol` would be (part of) the solution, but it
does NOT work in ESS, so it's pretty limited...

What should I bind to <kbd>F1</kbd>, then?

Comment: Doesn't `info-lookup-symbol` do most of what you are asking? (If you really need something that combines all of what you mention, then write a command that tests the context and calls the appropriate function (`describ-function` or whatever).) For Emacs thingies, maybe see also command `help-on-click/key` in [help+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/help%2b.el).

Comment: You're describing a missing feature of Emacs.  Feel free to `M-x report-emacs-bug` asking for that new feature.

Comment: Reported as bug #18346

Comment: @itsjeyd -- Thanks for editing the style of the key bindings and the function names!

Comment: No problem. Next time you'll know how to do it yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found this snippet somewhere on the internet a while ago, which can do this for Emacs lisp:

```
(defun describe-symbol-at-point ()
  "Get help for the symbol at point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((sym (intern-soft (current-word))))
    (unless
        (cond ((null sym))
              ((not (eq t (help-function-arglist sym)))
               (describe-function sym))
              ((boundp sym)
               (describe-variable sym)))
      (message "nothing"))))
```

Comment: This is nice to merge help on function + help on variable under one sole function. Though, in my tests, it only works with Emacs Lisp -- not with ESS (R), nor Shell, nor AWK, nor Java. Still thanks for this appetizer...